# Switch from Login to Billing payment experience profile

Tags: php, rest, paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to make a WebProfile for Paypal payment using REST API. I want to redirect user to login if he choose to pay with PayPal or direct user to the billing form if he choose the CreditCard payment.

I read the WebProfile docs and I found this param:
**landing_page_type** that could be "Billing" or "Login".

Therefore I created a webprofile with Billing landing type.

```
$flowConfig = new \PayPal\Api\FlowConfig();
$flowConfig->setLandingPageType("Billing");
$webProfile = new \PayPal\Api\WebProfile();
$webProfile->setName("YeowZa! T-Shirt Shop" . uniqid())
    ->setFlowConfig($flowConfig);
$createProfileResponse = $webProfile->create($apiContext);
```

I checked it listing all profiles of my account and I found that the landing_page_type param is correctly set.

When I use this profile for a new payment user is always redirect to classic Paypal login... why? All other params (brand name, logo, etc.) of the profile are well working.

I also tried to delete all cookies or use another browser, but I always have this problem.

Comment: Paypal assistance replies that actually there is no difference between "billing" and "paypal" landing page.